# Double Injection to Module Angular

Tags: angularjs

How can i inject `'ngSanitize'` and `'ngRoute'` both to module?

Now it looks like:

```
    var app = angular.module('board', ['ngSanitize']);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the second argument of the `module` function is an array of dependencies, so you can do it like:

```
var app = angular.module('board', ['ngSanitize', 'ngRoute']);
```